# Short circuit and voltage source

Tags: short-circuit

[image]

I don't understand why when you replace a wire between a and b with a short circuit, you could just ignore 160 Ix voltage source.

I understand that those two resistors in parallel will be shorted, but why the voltage source? And if that voltage source was to the left of a 20 ohm resistor, would it still be shorted?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Yes, sorry that I posted it here, didn't know that there was "Electrical Engineering" Sectio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ignore the \$160I_x\$ voltage source because \$I_x\$ is zero. \$I_x\$ is the current through the \$40\Omega\$ resistor and when we short circuit that resistor no current will pass through it, all the current will pass through the wire.

Comment: that makes so much sense right now, thank you! But if that voltage source was not dependent and it was parallel to short circuit or in series, it would not be shorted?

Comment: @student123 It will be short circuited if connected in parallel to the wire, but it is not a good idea to do so because an infinite current will pass through the wire, you will have a lot of sparks and the wire will heat up.